Largest exponential of a Hurwitz matrix
A matrix is Hurwitz if all its eigenvalues have negative real part. Is it true that
$$ \sup \left\{ \| e^A \| \mid A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \text{ is Hurwitz} \right\} < \infty ? $$
The answer will be the same for any matrix norm.
Any upper bounds on the answer?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is false even if the matrices are required to be diagonalisable. E.g. since
$$
\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{x\\ &y}\pmatrix{1&-t\\ 0&1}
=\pmatrix{x&t(y-x)\\ 0&y},
$$
we see that
\begin{align*}
f(t)&=\left\|\exp\left(\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{-2\\ &-1}\pmatrix{1&-t\\ 0&1}\right)\right\|\\
&=\left\|\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{e^{-2}\\ &e^{-1}}\pmatrix{1&-t\\ 0&1}\right\|\\
&=\left\|\pmatrix{e^{-2}&t(e^{-1}-e^{-2})\\ 0&e^{-1}}\right\|
\end{align*}
is not bounded above.

Splendid. Your counterexample shows that the logarithmic norm can be made arbitrarily large and positive, while maintaining a constant negative spectral abscissa.
